# Можно ли в вектор отправлять объект по ссылке?

Tags: c++, указатели, vector

Я ранее активно использовал C#, но понадобилось создать приложение на C++. И я не пойму, почему вектор не реагирует на изменения элементов.

Приведу пример из C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
        Book book1 = new Book();
        books.Add(book1);

        book1.id = 5; // на это изменение реагирует список *books*. То есть его элемент тоже теперь имеет id = 5
    }
}

class Book
{
    public int id = 1;
}
```

В данном случае элемент списка и объект ссылаются на один адрес, но у меня не получается сделать то же самое в C++

```
class Book
{
public:
    int id = 1;
};


int main()
{
    vector<Book> books;
    Book book1 = Book();

    books.push_back(book1);

    book1.id = 5;

    cout << &book1 << " " << &books[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Но справедливо заметил, что элемент вектора и **book1** ссылаются на разные адреса.
И я не пойму, почему там разные адреса, хотя в объявлении функции **push_back()** у вектора сказано, что объект получает ссылку, а не копию.

Если это невозможно в принципе, то нет ли обходного пути, чтоб напрямую не обращаться к элементу вектора?

Comment: Нет, лучше всего в таком случае использовать вектор указателей. Можно еще вектор от `reference_wrapper`, но это сложнее и запутаннее...

Comment: @Harry то есть vector<*Book>? Верно понимаю? И после получения придется их разыменовывать? Спасибо, что подсказали. попробую!

Comment: `vector<Book*>`

Comment: `book1` никуда не ссылается, это значение. В С++ все объекты не являются ссылочными типами, как в C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C++ контейнеры хранят объекты по значению. Для достижения поведения схожего с C#, достаточно использовать контейнер указателей, но чтобы не было заморочек с владением и временем жизни объектов, на которые эти указатели будут указывать, должны быть не обычные сырые сишные указатели, а их "умные" компаньоны. В данном случае вам проще всего подойдёт `std::shared_ptr`.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Book>> books;
auto book1 = std::make_shared<Book>();

books.push_back(book1);

book1->id = 5;

std::cout << book1.get() << " " << books[0].get() << '\n';
```